# How to filter elements by their distance to the beginning of a given ancestor element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, parsing

**Minimal example:** the expected behavior is specified by Jasmin tests:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function thereIsImportantContent(id) {
    return $(id).find("strong").filter(function() {
      var index = $(id).text().indexOf($(this).text());
      return 0 <= index && index <= 20;
    }).length > 0;
  }

  // specs code
  describe("thereIsImportantContent", function() {

    it("accept strong near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_1")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("accept strong near head with children", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_2")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("accept wrapped strong near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_3")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("reject strong further down", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_4")[0])).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it("reject strong further down with copies near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_5")[0])).toBeFalsy();
    });
  });

  // load jasmine htmlReporter
  (function() {
    var env = jasmine.getEnv();
    env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
    env.execute();
  }());
});
```

```css
container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<container id="test_case_1">
  <!-- strong content at the beginning -> accept -->
  <p>Some <strong>content</strong></p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_2">
  <!-- handle strong with children correctly -->
  <strong>Hey look: <span> content!</span></strong>
</container>

<container id="test_case_3">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Hey <strong>content!</strong></p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_4">
  <p>Something</p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <!-- strong content but located further down -> reject -->
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_5">
  <!-- same text as in strong below triggering false accept -->
  <p>Some content</p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <!-- strong content but located further down -> should eject -->
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>
```

---

My use case: as part of a user-script that tries to find potential titles of a website:

Assuming I have a website that looks like:

```
<container>
  <p>Some <strong>content</strong></p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>
```

I'm looking for a way, to find important looking elements like (e.g. h1, h2, strong, ...) that are visually near the start of the visible text.

Above code looks to the user something like this:

> Some **content** 
>   ... 
>   other text 
>   ... 
>   Hey look: **content**!

My current aproach was to evaluate `container.text().indexOf(elementOfIntrest.text())` and using only these with a low index...

```
container.find("strong").slice(0,10).filter(function () {
    var index = container.text().indexOf($(this).text());
    console.log("Testing: " + $(this).text(), " index: " + index);
    return 0 <= index && index <= 50
});
```

But I realized that this only works if the important content isn't present in the normal text at an earlier point.

For example:

```
<container>
   <p>Some content</p>  <---position where the text "content" was found and
                             ^                             wrongly accepted       
   ...                       |Potentially important  
   <p>really long text</p>   |Element with text "content"
   ...                       |should be ignored as its far away
                             |from the start of the text
   <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>
```

`indexOf` finds "content" from the strong element in the second line and accepts it.

---

**Q: how do I filter HTML elements efficiently by their distance to the beginning of a given ancestor element, counted in characters?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it properly, and based on [your current solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642822/9217760), here's one *equivalent* way of doing it in jQuery.

*The changes I made* are in between the `// The jQuery way start.` and `// The jQuery way end.`.

**UPDATE**

Merged with OP's edit (added new HTML / test case) and I replaced the JS code with a new one — `_findEls()`, which should do the job well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function findChildrenNearElementHead(element, selector, maxDistance = 15) {
    let curLen = 0,
      candidates = [];
    // The jQuery way start.
    function _findEls(el) {
      $(el).children().each(function() {
        if (curLen < maxDistance) {
          if ($(this).is(selector)) {
            candidates.push(this);
          } else if (this.firstElementChild /* it has children */ ) {
            /* only count text of element OR its children */
            return _findEls(this);
          }

          curLen += $(this).text().length;
        }
      });
    }

    _findEls(element);
    // The jQuery way end.

    return candidates;
  }

  function thereIsImportantContent(element) {
    return findChildrenNearElementHead(element, "h1,h2,strong").length > 0;
  }

  // specs code
  describe("findChildrenNearElementHead", function() {

    it("accept strong near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_1")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("accept strong near head with children", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_2")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("accept wrapped strong near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_3")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("reject strong further down", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_4")[0])).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it("reject strong further down with copies near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_5")[0])).toBeFalsy();
    });
  });

  // load jasmine htmlReporter
  (function() {
    var env = jasmine.getEnv();
    env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
    env.execute();
  }());
});
```

```css
container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<container id="test_case_1">
  <!-- strong content at the beginning -> accept -->
  <p>Some <strong>content</strong></p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_2">
  <!-- handle strong with children correctly -->
  <strong>Hey look: <span> content!</span></strong>
</container>

<container id="test_case_3">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Hey <strong> content!</strong></p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_4">
  <p>Something</p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <!-- strong content but located further down -> reject -->
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_5">
  <!-- same text as in strong below triggering false accept -->
  <p>Some content</p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <!-- strong content but located further down -> should eject -->
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>
```

Comment: That's almost it, just one last thing: After comprehending your idea I found one use case that I didn't consider before (so no test  for it)
It's about the firstChild, my solution doesn't limit itself to the first child it only starts there and then traverses the rest too through `nextSibling`. I proposed an edit to add the missing use case, could you try to adapt your solution?

Comment: On a second note: You misunderstood my usage of the depth variable, I use it to stop after I inspected all (grand*) children of my container while you use it to limit the result to one entry. Also from my understanding, `_addEle` is only called on elements that match the selector, the `textContent.length` of the other elements are ignored (nevertheless, it works, but I don't understand why)
That's the reason I don't like my solution: It's hard to understand, so not really maintainable.

Comment: I added comments for better understanding.

Comment: So, the only variable needed is the `maxDistance`? (Means we can ignore the `depth` variable?)

Comment: Ah okay, I'll check the comments.

Comment: I've updated the answer/code. Check it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Works without a hitch, many thanks. I proposed some minor changes to reduce the overhead, take a look if you like them if not, duno I have my answer, I will award you the bounty after it unlocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172335/discussion-between-fabian-n-and-sally-cj).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I aproached this problem from the wrong direction and now came up with the following solution:

1. Traverse DOM using depth-search and calculate the already processed text length by accumulating `element.textConent.length` of the children.
2. Proceed until no elements are left or the text has reached the given length limit.
3. While doing so cache all scanned elements that matched the given tag name / other criteria

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function findChildrenNearElementHead(element, selector, maxDistance = 15) {
    /* length of already processed text 
   (thats the number of characters the user has already read when he arives at the child element in question) */
    var curLen = 0;

    /* current depth in the DOM relative to the container element
    if negative we finised processing all elements in the container and shoudl stop */
    var depth = 0;

    // look for children that match this selector
    selector = selector.toUpperCase().split(",");

    // the result
    var candidates = [];

    // traverse complete DOM in container in pre-order
    while (curLen < maxDistance && depth >= 0) {
      // if element matches selector
      if (selector.indexOf(element.tagName) > -1) {
        // add element to result array
        candidates.push({
          "element": element,
          "index": curLen
        });

        // increase current text length by length of element
        curLen += element.textContent.length;
      } else if (element.firstElementChild) {
        /* if this element is not matched by the selector 
        and has children, dive in and look there for more elements */

        // begin with the first child element
        element = element.firstElementChild;

        // increase depth 
        depth += 1;

        // skip rest of current loop iteration
        continue;
      }

      // increase current text length by length of element
      curLen += element.textContent.length;

      // element has no children, has it siblings?
      if (element.nextElementSibling) {
        // yes it has -> continiue there
        element = element.nextElementSibling;

        /* element has no siblings
        go one layer up to parent and look there for siblings */
      } else if (element.parentElement.nextElementSibling) {
        // select next sibling of parent as active element
        element = element.parentElement.nextElementSibling;

        // descrease depth as we just moved one layer up
        depth -= 1;
      } else {

        // no children, no siblings, nothing to do
        break;
      }
    }

    return candidates;
  }

  function thereIsImportantContent(element) {
    return findChildrenNearElementHead(element, "h1,h2,strong").length > 0;
  }

  // specs code
  describe("findChildrenNearElementHead", function() {

    it("accept strong near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_1")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("accept strong near head with children", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_2")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("accept wrapped strong near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_3")[0])).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("reject strong further down", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_4")[0])).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it("reject strong further down with copies near head", function() {
      expect(thereIsImportantContent($("#test_case_5")[0])).toBeFalsy();
    });
  });

  // load jasmine htmlReporter
  (function() {
    var env = jasmine.getEnv();
    env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
    env.execute();
  }());
});
```

```css
container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<container id="test_case_1">
  <!-- strong content at the beginning -> accept -->
  <p>Some <strong>content</strong></p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_2">
  <!-- handle strong with children correctly -->
  <strong>Hey look: <span> content!</span></strong>
</container>

<container id="test_case_3">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Hey <strong>content!</strong></p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_4">
  <p>Something</p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <!-- strong content but located further down -> reject -->
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>

<container id="test_case_5">
  <!-- same text as in strong below triggering false accept -->
  <p>Some content</p>
  ...
  <p>other text</p>
  ...
  <!-- strong content but located further down -> should eject -->
  <p>Hey look: <strong>content</strong>!</p>
</container>
```

**Plunker copy:** https://embed.plnkr.co/YjLVxVHAWj0kDhoceRGK/

---

While this does exactly what I want I'm unsatisfied with the amount of code involved considering that we have libraries like jQuery.

I'm hoping that someone can come up with a more compact way to accomplish this.